# Unable to create SSLContext Neo4j

Tags: ssl, jdbc, neo4j, restlet

I'm creating an Enterprise Application in Netbeans 8.0.1 with Glassfish 4.1.1 that use Neo4j as graph database. I try to connect to Neo4j in a JSF Managed Bean with the JDBC Driver:

```
public void neo4jCall() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474","neo4j","***");
        try(Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()){
            stmt.executeQuery("CREATE (n:Person { name : 'Lucas', title : 'Employee'})");
        }
}
```

When I run the enterprise application I obtain the following exception:

```
Avvertenza:   Unable to start the Restlet
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create SSLContext.
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.configure(HttpClientHelper.java:287)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.start(HttpClientHelper.java:513)
    at org.restlet.Client.start(Client.java:186)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:315)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:159)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1104)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1664)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1112)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1188)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1059)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1035)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:937)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:645)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources$DiscoveryClientResource.readInformation(Resources.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.createExecutor(Neo4jConnection.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.<init>(Neo4jConnection.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections$4.doCreate(Connections.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections.create(Connections.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:37)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at TestJSFManagBeans.neo4jCall(TestJSFManagBeans.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:322)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.configure(HttpClientHelper.java:284)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 78 more

Avvertenza:   Unable to start the Restlet
Avvertenza:   Unable to start the Restlet
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create SSLContext.
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.configure(HttpClientHelper.java:287)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.start(HttpClientHelper.java:513)
    at org.restlet.Client.start(Client.java:186)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:315)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:159)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1104)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1664)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1112)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1664)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1112)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1188)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1059)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1035)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:937)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:645)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources$DiscoveryClientResource.readInformation(Resources.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.createExecutor(Neo4jConnection.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.<init>(Neo4jConnection.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections$4.doCreate(Connections.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections.create(Connections.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:37)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at TestJSFManagBeans.neo4jCall(TestJSFManagBeans.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:322)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.configure(HttpClientHelper.java:284)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 80 more

Avvertenza:   Unable to start the Restlet
Avvertenza:   #{test.neo4jCall()}: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
javax.faces.FacesException: #{test.neo4jCall()}: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:599)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1165)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1060)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1035)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:937)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:645)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources$DiscoveryClientResource.readInformation(Resources.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.createExecutor(Neo4jConnection.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.<init>(Neo4jConnection.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections$4.doCreate(Connections.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections.create(Connections.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:37)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at TestJSFManagBeans.neo4jCall(TestJSFManagBeans.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:347)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:114)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:112)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:162)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1104)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1664)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1112)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1664)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1112)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1188)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1059)
    ... 63 more

Grave:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:599)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1165)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1060)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1035)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:937)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:645)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources$DiscoveryClientResource.readInformation(Resources.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.createExecutor(Neo4jConnection.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.<init>(Neo4jConnection.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections$4.doCreate(Connections.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections.create(Connections.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:37)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at TestJSFManagBeans.neo4jCall(TestJSFManagBeans.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:347)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:114)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:112)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:162)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1104)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1664)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1112)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1664)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1112)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1188)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1059)
    ... 63 more
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What are you doing with JAX-RS? No dependency of RestLet / JAX-RS can be found in the question.

Comment: @Tiny: I think neo4j uses this as a 'transport' mechanism. I already updated the tags https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/issues/36

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje but I have noticed that the issue is still open on GitHub.